# How to keep the information from one line to another page

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm displaying a list of cars using datatable.

Basically the list is componed of lines similar to this one:

```
ferrari - red - 1993 - 4 wheels - edit
```

When I press Edit, I'd like to open a new page especially for this car with all these informations.
Basically the edit button calls a carview function. I can get the object car from this function but I don't know how to send it to a new page (mycaar.xhtml) and display it.

```
    public String details(Car car) {
    return "mycar.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&carId=" + car.getCarId();
}
```

How could I do that ?

Comment: can you add your basic xhtml file and managedBean code?

Comment: Why dont you use [f:param](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/4-ways-to-pass-parameter-from-jsf-page-to-backing-bean/)  to pass the id?